# make Label control text look as good as it does in VS form designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, fonts, textbox

In VS2008 I designed a form for a C# dll. The dll is a plugin for a somewhat older app (ca. 2005): let's call it "OldApp". In VS form designer, the text in Label controls on my form is nicely rendered: antialiased and properly kerned. But when I bring up this form within OldApp (where the C# dll runs as a plugin), the text in Label controls looks ugly. It's legible, but the kerning is poor: the letters are spaced further apart and at seemingly random offsets. Anything I can do to make the text labels from within OldApp look as good as they do in VS's form designer? I doubt the specific font matters, but it's Arial, 7.2 pt (VS2008 default). I tried playing with the two relevant lines in Program.cs (see below), to no effect.

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles(); // tried using it and commenting it out
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(true); // tried true and false
```

Comment: Are you executing the old application on the same machine as your Visual Studio? The reason I ask is that the formatting of the application may depend on the operating system. Something running on Windows 7 might look different on a Windows XP machine.

Comment: Have you tried to increase the font-size? Try setting it to 12pt and see if you still experience this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar problem on MSDN forums that mentions adding the following line after the EnableVisualStyles() method.

```
Application.DoEvents()
```

Seems to be a bug in older .NET versions...which version are you using?

Comment: Tried it, but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

After an investigation I have some findings, so I'll just answer my own question:

1. The bad news: the old-style text rendering used by OldApp **is** what's causing the problem. I verified it by toggling the **UseCompatibleTextRendering** property for the label control in VS. The font distortion I see is **the same** one I see in OldApp. Which means that the **Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false)** line in my code has **no effect**. OldApp will **ignore it** and do old-style rendering anyway.
2. As suggested by DeviantSeev using a bigger font helps a bit. It doesn't get rid of the bad kerning, it just makes it less noticeable. I increased the font from 7.2pt to 8pt only (not 12pt), because the dialog box becomes too big otherwise. The way to do this is in the **form's** Font property (not the control's). This way, you'll change **all controls** uniformly (if their Font property is set to default).
3. The font sizes in VS appear to be discrete rather than continuous, or maybe there's an **int()** rounding off involved. Increasing the font from 7.2pt to 7.4pt results in very little change, while at 7.5pt the font makes a sudden jump in size.
4. Forms have an **AutoScaleMode** property. If it's set to **Font** and the form is **resizeable**, the form will resize in VS in proportion to the change in font size. This way, in VS you can find an acceptable middle ground between a (legible) font size and a bloated dialog. However, be careful: the auto-scale operation can suddenly go awry, for example if you change the Font **units** from points to pixels, inches, etc. You may suddenly end up with microscopic controls or a form bigger than your screen and hitting **undo won't fix it**. You really don't want to re-design your form again, so save it **before** any font unit change and then again when you're happy with what you see.